# Seemingly incorrect guide color when geom_line() and geom_segment() are used together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm drawing some line segments on top of a plot that uses geom_line(). Surprisingly, the guide (legend) colors for geom_line() are drawn as the color of the last element I add to the plot - even if it is not the geom_line(). This looks like a bug to me, but it could be expected behavior for some reason I don't understand.

```
#Set up the data
require(ggplot2)
x <- rep(1:10, 2)
y <- c(1:10, 1:10+5)
fac <- gl(2, 10)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, fac=fac)

#Draw the plot with geom_segment second, and the guide is the color of the segment
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, linetype=fac)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=2, y=7, xend=7, yend=7), colour="red")
```

[image: When geom_segment() comes after geom_line()]

Whereas if I add the geom_segment first, the colors on the guide are black as I would expect:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, linetype=fac)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=2, y=7, xend=7, yend=7), colour="red") +
  geom_line()
```

[image: When geom_line() comes after geom_segment()]

Feature or bug? If the first, can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: Add: `, show_guide=FALSE` to the `geom_segment`

Comment: OK, but why does it show up on the guide at all? I would expect that geom_segment is meant to be 'outside' of the data, so it wouldn't normally influence the guide - and if it did, the order that you add it to the plot shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature(ish). The guide that is drawn is a guide for linetype. But, it has to be drawn in some color to be seen. When the color is not specified by an aesthetic mapping, ggplot2 draws it in a color that is consistent with the plot. I'm speculating that the default is whatever last color was used. That is why you are seeing differences when you plot them in a different order.

However, you can control these details of the legend.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, linetype=fac)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=2, y=7, xend=7, yend=7), colour="red") +
  scale_linetype_discrete(guide=guide_legend(override.aes=aes(colour="blue")))
```

[image]